# Can you tell the name of this spider?

Tags: species-identification

This image has been posted on the [Wikimedia Commons](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Une_grosse_araign%C3%A9e_verte_dans_potager_dans_le_centre_de_la_France.jpg)

[image]

This spider is about 3~4cm long. It was found in the middle of tomatoes plants in a garden, in the center of France, Clermont-Ferrand. Photo taken in the early days of August. It would be interesting to specify the species on [Wikimedia Commons](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Une_grosse_araign%C3%A9e_verte_dans_potager_dans_le_centre_de_la_France.jpg).

Please let me know if you need other information.

Comment: Apparently, Americans aren't the only ones to use their currency as unit of length $\ddot \smile$. I changed the unit from "2 € coin" to "cm". I edited a few other things. I am not sure what you meant by `specify the species on Commons` though, so I left it unchanged.

Comment: Thanks. You're right. Commons refers to the Wikimedia fundation site where the image is hosted. These images are often used as illustrations on the different Wikipedias so that adding the specie in the description would be a great added value.

Answer (score 3):

This is a wasp spider (Agriope bruennichi)

See here: [Wasp spider](https://www.myheimat.de/augsburg/natur/wespenspinne-argiope-bruennichi-auch-zebraspinne-genannt-d2825597.html)

The link leads to a German Website showing the belly side of a wasp spider

Or see here: [Wasp spider II](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argiope_bruennichi#/media/File%3AWasp_spider_(Argiope_bruennichi)_underside%2C_showing_stabilimentum.jpg)